# ¿Cómo poner un estado personalizado en discord con discord.py?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

Estoy intentando ponerle a mi bot de discord hecho con Python un estado personalizado, solo con texto, que no use `Listening`, `Streaming`, `Playing` o `Watching`. Por ejemplo, que ponga *Comiendo galletas*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actualmente hay 5 estados en Discord y son: `Listening`, `Streaming`, `Listening`, `Custom` y `Competing`. En este caso sería `Custom`.

```
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    custom = discord.Custom('Prueba')
    await bot.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online, activity=custom)
    print('Prueba')
```

En vez de `Prueba` debes escribir el texto que tú quieras poner.